# What is the lesson of the "make straight paths" metaphor in Hebrews 12:13?

Tags: hebrews, metaphor

Hebrews 12:13  (NASB)

> "And make straight paths for your feet, so that the limb which is lame may not be put out of joint, but rather be healed."

Answer (score 1):

A.V.  Romans 9:32 "they stumbled at that stumbling stone", :33 "whosoever believeth on him shall not be ashamed". The background to paths and rocks 2000 years ago was that e.g. the road from Jericho to Jerusalem twisted around large rocks where robbers could hide and small rocks could trip one up. The New Testament writers took this and used it as an image of our relationship with Jesus Christ. Either due to disbelief we would stumble and be ashamed, or through faith in Jesus our walk would be straight and smooth.